# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.gtts'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python, gtts

I am trying to convert a text to speech in python using gtts I am using the 3.7.4 version of python but whenever I use gtts ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.gtts'; '**main**' is not a package or the sometimes it says gtts module cannot be imported 
`from .gtts import gTTS
text2speech = gTTS(text = "HEllo guys",lang = 'en')
text2speech.save('sample.mp3')`
//
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/text2speech.py", line 1, in 
    from .gtts import gTTS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.gtts'; '**main**' is not a package//
please hep me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

its

```
from gtts import gTTS
```

instead of

```
from .gtts import gTTS
```

Comment: same error? are you using your environment, can you show your pip list use ```pip list```

Comment: C:\Users\DELL>pip list
Package           Version   
----------------- ----------
astroid           2.3.2     
beautifulsoup4    4.8.2     
certifi           2019.11.28
chardet           3.0.4     
Click             7.0       
colorama          0.4.1     
comtypes          1.1.7     
cycler            0.10.0    
Django            2.2.5     
docopt            0.6.2     
future            0.18.2    
gTTS              2.1.1
gTTS-token        1.1.3
idna              2.9

Comment: isort             4.3.21
joblib            0.14.0
Js2Py             0.68
kiwisolver        1.1.0
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3     
matplotlib        3.1.1     
mccabe            0.6.1     
mysqlclient       1.4.4     
numpy             1.17.3
packaging         20.3
pandas            0.25.3    
pip               20.0.2
pipwin            0.4.7
PyAudio           0.2.11
pyglet            1.5.0
pyjsparser        2.7.1     
pylint            2.4.3
pyparsing         2.4.5
PyPrind           2.11.2    
python-dateutil   2.8.1
pyttsx3           2.81

Comment: pytz              2019.2
requests          2.23.0
scikit-learn      0.21.3
scipy             1.3.1
setuptools        46.0.0
six               1.12.0
soupsieve         1.9.5
SpeechRecognition 3.8.1
sqlparse          0.3.0
typed-ast         1.4.0
tzlocal           2.0.0
urllib3           1.25.8
wheel             0.34.2
wrapt             1.11.2

Comment: please look over it this is the pip list i have gTTS 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

This error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.gtts'; '__main__' is not a package` may also occur if you have named the main program file you created as `__main__.py` and try to run it as `python __main__.py` or another file has the name `__main__.py` in the same folder from which you run your program. Python will consider your program file as a module and try to find something in it that is naturally not in it. About where Python is looking for modules, see [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

In this case, rename your program file so that its name does not equal with the name of the imported module.